# SQl query across 2 tables with conditional

Tags: sql, myob

Using the MYOB database I want to query across two tables.

I have the following inner join occuring and it's linked between the ShippingMethodID.

```
 INNER JOIN ShippingMethods ON Sales.ShippingMethodID = ShippingMethods.ShippingMethodID
```

There is a field I want to use in the ShippingMethods table called ShippingMethod which has string values for the actual shipping method.

Inside my WHERE section I want to test for `ShippingsMethods.ShippingMethod = Post` , for example. But my sales table, I only have the ID to go by, and I'm never certain of the index number.

How might I Run a WHERE statement that links the two tables to a required value?

Comment: The `where` condition `ShippingsMethods.ShippingMethod = 'Post'` should work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also add the condition to the join

```
INNERJOIN ShippingMethods ON (Sales.ShippingMethodID = ShippingMethods.ShippingMethodID  
        AND ShippingsMethods.ShippingMethod = 'Post')
```